# Expected Value help

Tags: probability

A fair coin is tossed. If a head occurs 1 die is rolled, if a tail occurs 2 dice are rolled. Let X be the total on the die or dice. What is E[X]?

To be honest, I don't get this. The answer was supposed to be 5.25. What I tried is that if X is the total on the die or dice, then x is ranging from 1-12 (1-6 for a die and 2-12 for the dice). And I don't know how to proceed anymore. Please help.

Comment: What is the expected value of the roll of a single die?

Comment: SInce we have a .5 chance for a head to occur in a toss of a coin, and the total of a die is from 1-6 then .5(1)+.5(2)+..+.5(6)=10.5 . Am I right on assuming this? If this is the case, I cant see how i'll get 5.25

Comment: No. It looks like there are a few issues here, so it might be a good idea to review the formula for expected probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected value is calculated by using $$E[X] = x_1p_1+x_2p_2+\cdots+x_kp_k$$

Case 1 = head occurs
The expected value on the die is calculated as follows  $$\begin{align}E[X\mid \textsf{Heads }] = ~& 1\cdot \frac{1}{6} + 2\cdot \frac{1}{6} + 3\cdot \frac{1}{6} + 4\cdot \frac{1}{6} + 5\cdot \frac{1}{6}+ 6\cdot \frac{1}{6}\\[1ex] = ~& 3.5\end{align}$$

Case 2 = tail occurs
The expected total value to see on the dice is $$\begin{align}E[X\mid \textsf{Tails }] =~&{\Big( 1\cdot \frac{1}{6} + 2\cdot \frac{1}{6} + 3\cdot \frac{1}{6} + 4\cdot \frac{1}{6} + 5\cdot \frac{1}{6}+ 6\cdot \frac{1}{6} \Big) \\ + \Big(1\cdot \frac{1}{6} + 2\cdot \frac{1}{6} + 3\cdot \frac{1}{6} + 4\cdot \frac{1}{6} + 5\cdot \frac{1}{6}+ 6\cdot \frac{1}{6} \Big)} \\[2ex] =7\end{align}$$

(NB: This uses *Linearity of Expectation*.   The expected sum of two dies' results *is* the sum of the expectations of each die's result.)

Now for the final result, since the probability of both cases are $\frac{1}{2}$ , the expected value $$\begin{align}E[X] ~=~ & 3.5 \cdot \frac{1}{2} + 7 \cdot\frac{1}{2}\\[1ex] =~& 5.25\end{align}$$

(NB: This is the *Law of Total Expectation* at work.)

Comment: Why the downvote?? If you see something wrong then state it.

Comment: When two dice are rolled, the value of $X$ can be $2$ to $12$ and probability for them will be different.

Comment: I will up vote this because I do not see the reason for the down vote

Comment: @stanleydodds, your answer may be correct, but procedure is not formal.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay No, what I've done is, calculating the expected value on each die then summing them up. The expected sum is equal to the sum of expected value on each die. So, nothing is wrong with that.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay I see no reason to solve this question in $2* \frac{1}{36} + 3* \frac{1}{36} + 3* \frac{1}{36} + .. 12* \frac{1}{36}$ way

Comment: yes, it is true that you could write out all 36 combinations, but this can then be factorised into the expression given.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay I have edited my answer to show you why this method works, giving a correct answer. Could you remove the down vote now? my answer is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T$ be the count of tails on the coin toss (ie $0$ for heads, $1$ for tails).   Thus can partition the space over these two disjoint events, using the Law of Total Expectation.   Because it is a fair coin: $$\mathsf P(T=0)~=~\mathsf P(T=1)\\~~~=~\tfrac 12$$

Let $X$ be the sum of the dice results, and $X_1,X_2$ be the result of the individual dice rolled.   The later two are independent and identically distributed.   Then we can evaluate the conditional expectation of $X$ given the coin results.
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X\mid T=0)~=~&\mathsf E(X_1)\\[1ex]\mathsf E(X\mid T=1)~=~&\mathsf E(X_1+X_2)\end{align}$$

Because Expectation is Linear we have: $$\mathsf E(X_1+X_2)~=~\mathsf E(X_1)+\mathsf E(X_2)$$

Because the individual dice are independent and identically distributed, then: $$\mathsf E(X_1)~=~\mathsf E(X_2)$$

Finally we know the expected result of a single die is $\tfrac 72$
$$\mathsf E(X_1)~=~\tfrac {1+2+3+4+5+6} 6$$

---

All together now:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(X) ~=~ & \mathsf E(X\mid T=0)~\mathsf P(T=0)+\mathsf E(X\mid T=1)~\mathsf P(T=1) & \textrm{Law of Total Expectation}
\\[1ex] ~=~& \tfrac 1 2\Big(\mathsf E(X\mid T=0)+\mathsf E(X\mid T=1)\Big) & \textrm{Fair Coin}
\\[1ex] ~=~& \tfrac 1 2\Big(\mathsf E(X_1)+\mathsf E(X_1+X_2)\Big) &\textrm{How many die are rolled}
\\[1ex] ~=~& \tfrac 1 2\Big(\mathsf E(X_1)+\mathsf E(X_1)+\mathsf E(X_2)\Big) & \textrm{Linearity of Expectation}
\\[1ex] ~=~& \tfrac 3 2\mathsf E(X_1) & \mathsf E(X_1)=\mathsf E(X_2)
\\[1ex] ~=~ & \tfrac 32\cdot\tfrac 72 & \mathsf E(X_1)=\tfrac 7 2
\\[1ex] ~=~ & \tfrac{21}{4}
\\[1ex] ~=~ & 5.25
\end{align}$$

$\Box$

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I would first calculate the expected value of a single dice:

${1+2+3+4+5+6\over6}={7\over2}$

So that the expected value of two die is:

${7\over2}+{7\over2}=7$

Then, the overall expected value is:

${7+{7\over2}\over2}={21\over4}=5.25$

This method is only possible because all dice rolls occur with equal probability (1/6) and both heads and tails occur with equal probability (1/2). The previous answer works under any circumstance.

Here I will give a detailed explanation of the two-dice expected value:

The expected value could be written as:

${1\over36}(1+1)+{1\over36}(1+2)+\dots+{1\over36}(1+6)+$

${1\over36}(2+1)+{1\over36}(2+2)+\dots+{1\over36}(2+6)+\dots$

${1\over36}(6+1)+{1\over36}(6+2)+\dots+{1\over36}(6+6)$

and then expanded and factorised to give:

${1\over36}(12\times1)+{1\over36}(12\times2)+\dots+{1\over36}(12\times6)$

which can be further factorise to give:

$2\times{1\over6}(1+2+3+4+5+6)={7\over2}+{7\over2}=7$

This is why my method works in this case.

Comment: why have you down voted mine? I have explained that this does not always work, why is this the wrong answer?

Comment: I'm confused as to why there are two copies of this entire answer. To avoid losing the reputation from either one, perhaps you should ask the moderators to merge the answers.